# deploy jar file using Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, jar

How to deploy a jar file using Jenkins deployment jobs?
Is there any specific plugin available for jar deployments.

For War or EAR, we can go to Jenkins_deployment Jobs >> Post-build Actions >> Deploy war/ear to a container - and provide the below info.

1. WAR/EAR files,
2. Context path,
3. Containers

Can anyone please help in this?

Comment: To where do you want to deploy the war file? There are too many options here.. what about SSH?

Comment: Please note that questions asking for general help or recommendations for plugins are off topic "*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*". See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Most containers have a directory where you can "place" the war, in order to deploy it.

Therefore in Jenkins you can set up `Send build artifacts over SSH`

Name: `my_server123` (You must have a configured server)

Transfers: Transfer set:

```
source files: `path/to/target/*.war
remove prefix: `path/to/target
```

On configuring the server, you should go in `Configure Jenkins` -> `Configure system` -> `SSH Servers`

Add the server you need to deploy to, username (+password)  and Remote directory: `/opt/app/tomcat/webapps` (or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send artifacts from windows build server to linux machine you can use send artifact over ssh from build section

If you want to send artifact from windows build server to windows application server you can use robocopy

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at [the SCP plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SCP+plugin)

> This plugin uploads build artifacts to repository sites using SCP (SSH) protocol.